# Replacing macros in RTF file/template

Tags: c#, rtf

I am doing a fairly (at least i assumed so) operation.
I have a RTF file with Macros in it.

I wrote a c# console application, in which i use System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox component.

Short version:

```
RichTextBox rtb=new RichTextBox();
rtb.LoadFile(input,RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
foreach(var macroPair in dictionary)
{
   while (rtb.Find(macroPair.Key) > -1)
   {
      rtb.Select(rtb.Find(macroPair.Key), macroPair.Key.Length);
      rtb.SelectedText = macroPair.Value;
   }
}
rtb.SaveFile(outputRichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

however, this looses a lot of formating (color, table, new line etc and even some of the relace macros) :(

Alternative was to use replace directly on rtb.Rtf but there the problem was the same when doing a direct replacement on the file itself without RichTextbox: RTF doesnt have to save the text uninterupted, ie(cant find example, maybe invalid: Macro\f252Key.
When you open the RTF it shows MacroKey ok, but i can't get it to save that way too :(

Thanks for any insight

Example:

This's a copypaste from an RTF:

```
Contract No:  \tab %}{{\*\bkmkstart __DdeLink__5913_841230768}\dbch\af3\rtlch \ltrch\loch\lang1033
DEFAULT.}{{\*\bkmkend __DdeLink__5913_841230768}\dbch\af3\rtlch \ltrch\loch\lang1033
CONTRACT_REALID%}
```

As you can seem %DEFAULT. and CONTRACT_REALID% are separated by rtf formating for some reason (nothing i can see in an RTF editor) so direct simple string replacement doesnt work here

***Solution***

So the solution i posted earlier using regexp to replace, didnt work out...
But in the end it was still regexp, but instead of searching for a concreate macro inside the RTF i did it the other way around:

First i matched all macros in the RTF using following RegEx:

```
string sideregexp = @"[\{\}\\a-zA-Z0-9_*:\s ]+";
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(input, "%" + sideregexp + @"\." + sideregexp + "%", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

This returns me everything that should/could be an Macro

Often it returns something like this:

> %}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af1  \ltrch\fcs0 \fs20\insrsid13847909
>   \hich\af1\dbch\af31505\loch\f1 MACROSET.MACRO}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af1
>   \ltrch\fcs0 \fs20\lang1036\langfe1033\langnp1036\insrsid13847909
>   \hich\af1\dbch\af31505\loch\f1 %

So i sanitaze it using the folowing regex:

```
Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(mc[index].Value, @"([\\}{]|(__))+[a-zA-Z_\\*0-9\n}{\r]+[ \n\r]", ""), "[\n\r ]", "")
```

Afterwards, i check and for each macro i selected from the DB i do a "bridge test" (not sure what better word to use)

So if i have this string in rtf:

> %}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af1  \ltrch\fcs0 \fs20\insrsid13847909
>   \hich\af1\dbch\af31505\loch\f1 MACROSET.MACRO}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af1
>   \ltrch\fcs0 \fs20\lang1036\langfe1033\langnp1036\insrsid13847909
>   \hich\af1\dbch\af31505\loch\f1 %

which sanitezed is equal to:

> %MACROSET.MACRO%

and i have a KeyValuePair like :

> %MACROSET.MACRO% = SomeValue

I do some magic and get a Dictionary of KeyValuepairs like:

> %}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af1  \ltrch\fcs0 \fs20\insrsid13847909
>   \hich\af1\dbch\af31505\loch\f1 MACROSET.MACRO}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af1
>   \ltrch\fcs0 \fs20\lang1036\langfe1033\langnp1036\insrsid13847909
>   \hich\af1\dbch\af31505\loch\f1 % = SomeValue

And then i replace those.
If i dont have Macro KeyValuePAir from database it is ignored and skiped.

will keep updated as how succesful this is.

Comment: An example of the rtf code would be helpful

Comment: This's a copypaste from an RTF:

Contract No:  \tab %}{{\*\bkmkstart __DdeLink__5913_841230768}\dbch\af3\rtlch \ltrch\loch\lang1033
DEFAULT.}{{\*\bkmkend __DdeLink__5913_841230768}\dbch\af3\rtlch \ltrch\loch\lang1033
CONTRACT_REALID%}
As you can seem %DEFAULT. and CONTRACT_REALID% are separated by rtf formating for some reason (nothing i can see in an RTF editor) so direct simple string replacement doesnt work here

Comment: These are bookmarks, that's why you can't see them. You can remove them with regex if you don't need them. Another question: how do you want the rtf to look like after modification?

Comment: I want the RTF to look EXACTLY the same. It is suposed to be right now a simple plain text replacement with no change to formating, maybe just few things like newlines or tabulators.

I think right now that the issue i am haveing can be caused by the templates being created in OpenOffice/LibreOffice and from what i have been capable of finding out,  their RTF implementations are supposed to suck

Answer (score 0):

RTF format is plain text based. No need to load it in RichTextBox: you should be able to load it into e.g. StringBuilder, then search and replace your tags. Just don't forget to escape the values you're inserting: `{`, `}`, `\` should become `\{`, `\}`, and `\\`, and any character with code >=128 should become `\u####?` where #### is decimal UTF-16 code unit number.

Or, if you want more reliable solution (e.g. one use case when my method will fail - if the formatting changes within a single macro key) you could thy [this 3-rd party component](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter).

Comment: this is a nice solution, problem is that RTF is capable to intermix text and formating data, ie: This is some {rtf formatin} text